# Run Android script .ch in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I try to run command from my activity

```
Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());
outputStream.writeBytes(s+"\n");
outputStream.flush();
```

But I get many syntax errors

How I can run Android script .ch in Visual Studio C#?

Does I need root privileges?

Comment: I make application for Android in MS Visual Studio. I want to run native script Android (*.ch) from my application. How I can do it?

Comment: Your code is Java, you need to convert it to C#. And you should have root privileges in your device, otherwise, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Java.Lang.Process suProcess = Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("su");
Java.IO.DataOutputStream streamСommand = new Java.IO.DataOutputStream(suProcess.OutputStream);
streamСommand.WriteBytes("mkdir /sdcard/111\n");
streamСommand.WriteBytes("exit\n");
streamСommand.Flush();
streamСommand.Close();
suProcess.WaitFor();
```

Root is needed.